# vBulletin date decode from database

Tags: php, database, date, vbulletin

I need to use information from vBulletin database using external script. I need to decode join/last visit date. I found it in database but 06-02-2012 is in database encoded as 1338661020. How to decode it back to 06-02-2012 (in PHP) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use DateTime (which is a more robust solution).

```
$date = new DateTime('@1338661020');
echo $date->format(DATE_ATOM);
```

This also allows you to handle things like custom timezones per-user easily.

More info is available on php.net: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

Just found out :

```
echo date(DATE_ATOM, "1338661020");
```